# Cannot create a project in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I create a new project in vs2010, it shows that

> "server tfsserver1\Test1 doesn't offer team foundation server".

I'm confusing that my tfs server is tfsserver1, and vs2010 can connect to tfsserver1 too. What's tfsserver1\Test1? I reinstalled vs2010, but the problem still exists. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: How could anyne outside of your site possibly know what that server is, or how it got into your settings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess just becuase my vs2010 been destroyed by something reason,when I reinstall it, everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010, go to the `Team` menu, and click on `Connect To Team Foundation Server`.

In the dialog that pops up, click the `Servers..` button to see which servers you're connected to, and add and remove them as required.

Comment: Thank you! When I click the servers button, it shows tfsserver1, and it can connet to the server,too. what let me puzzled is the "tfsserver1\Test1", I don't know where it come from and why I reinstalled vs2010,it still existed?